# Google Calendar - Wordpress Simple Booking System

Tags: wordpress, google-calendar-api, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to create this:
-on my wordpress site, either add a shortcode or use a custom page template that will have the following functionality:
Show either a dropdown or calendar with available (free) times that are not busy from Google Calendar. The availability is a set schedule for shifts - one 3 hr shift every day. Monday-Fri 5-8pm and weekends 10am-1pm. Then the user can click on the calendar booking or dropdown to select an available shift to book. The name of the event will be (the user CANNOT change this) their full name as in their wordpress user profile, and the time will be the one 3 hr shift based on the day they selected (e.g. Mon Jan 1 5-8pm). This will be added to my Google calendar. That's it - no need for any other actions. Just a super simple shifts booking tool.
Can someone please advise how to do this or help me do it. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First You can go to the [google developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) page and create credentials for google calendar API. After that you can follow the steps given in link https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php